# Design pattern to display a 'New' overlay image

Tags: java, design-patterns, user-interface

An overlay image on top of a menu item is being displayed in a front end UI until a configuration option is set to false. Once set to false the UI element will not be displayed again. Here is the current flow :

in .jsp : read value from java class.
Within the java code this is how this boolean variable is set :
A boolean variable isOn is set to indicate wether or not the image is displayed.
Within a controller class invoke a static method which in turn calls a service which returns a value which resolves to a boolean value.

Because this image may be overlayed throughout the app for different menu items and the overlay may be turned on/off independent of each menu item I think I should use a design pattern. The command pattern spring to mind.

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Instead of explaining how the code behaves, show us **the codez** to receive better guidance.

Comment: It seems like you could use Decorator, but I need more details to be sure...